# Delete the originary (english) input language in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, language

I have an english version of windows 10 which I use in Germany for 3-4 years. So I had delete english input method and install german. Unfortunatelly since any update in the last weeks the english input language/method is appeared again and I cannot delete the input language method anymore. I set german as default input method, but  it seems for me, that there is no longer the possibility to delete the originary input language method.